# Error on live server and not on local server

Tags: c#, asp.net, localization

I get an error

```
CS0122: 'Resources.BrakeShoe' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

on this line

```
Line 12:        <asp:Panel DefaultButton="btnSearchPart" ID="divSearch" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" CssClass="form-horizontal divSearch">
Line 13:             <div class="control-group">
Line 14:                 <label class="control-label"><%=Resources.BrakeShoe.BS_DrumDia %></label>
Line 15:                 <div class="controls">
Line 16:                     <span>From:</span>
```

I'm getting it only after publish the project and upload it to my server.
on my development computer everything work fine.
I tried to delete all files and upload them again and it's dosen't work.

Comment: sorry if this a variable then you have to experiment it might be set to private I would use protected

Comment: its a resx file, the class is internal

Comment: Resources.BrakeShoe is it a variable or a file

Comment: Resources.BrakeShoe is a file

Comment: then the folder where the file is might have a security level try giving the permision read write to IIS if this is the issue

Comment: the files are in folder "App_GlobalResources" do i have to give it a special permissions?

Comment: yes try giving permission to "IUSR","IIS_USERS" with : Read,Execute,List.

Comment: it's still dont work i gave all permission to "IUSR","IIS_USERS"

Answer (score 0):

Error states that BrakeShoe is not accessible, make BrakeShoe public rebuild and deploy may help.

You can revere engineer your existing dll to find if BrakeShoe has proper access specifier.